# Adding instead of Overwriting PHP include path

Tags: php

I have my "main"-script `aaa.php` which has the php include path set to for directory `/root/asd` + `/usr/share/xyz`.

I require the script `bbb.php` which sets the php include path to directory `/root/xxx`.

The problem now is:

When I require another script `ccc.php` which is included in the directory `/root/asd` it cant be found because script bbb.php overwrote the include path value.

So my question is: Is there a way to **add** another include path if it hasn't already been included? Instead of overwriting the value.

Comment: Can you add some code examples how the script aaa.php, bbb.php and ccc.php get included and some of the contents?

Comment: If you are using ```set_include_path()``` then you can append paths with a ```:```. eg. ```set_include_path("/root/asd:/usr/share/xyz:/root/asd");```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like they do in ZF:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
  realpath('/path/to/your/include/directory'),
  get_include_path(),
)))
```

So, you just add one directory to the existing ones ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, i think i found an answer that provides the exact functionality i was looking for:

```
if(!in_array("/root/asd", explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path())))
    set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR."/root/asd");
```

This checks the included paths and, if needed, adds the new path.